# Pandas read in table without headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Using pandas, how do I read in only a subset of the columns (say 4th and 7th columns) of a .csv file with no headers? I cannot seem to be able to do so using `usecols`.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Previous answers were good and correct, but in my opinion, an extra `names` parameter will make it perfect, and it should be the recommended way, especially when the csv has no `headers`.

## Solution

#### Use `usecols` and `names` parameters

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, usecols=[3,6], names=['colA', 'colB'])
```

## Additional reading

or use `header=None` to explicitly tells people that the `csv` has no headers (anyway both lines are **identical**)

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, usecols=[3,6], names=['colA', 'colB'], header=None)
```

So that you can retrieve your data by

```
# with `names` parameter
df['colA']
df['colB']
```

instead of

```
# without `names` parameter
df[0]
df[1]
```

#### Explain

Based on [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), when `names` are passed explicitly, then `header` will be behaving like `None` instead of `0`, so one can skip `header=None` when `names` exist.

Comment: I don't really understand why it's so unclearly explained in the docs. They mentioned `header=None` only once there, and it's: "then the behavior is identical to `header=None`". But what is this behavior? It's just not mentioned. Should I treat it as I should avoid using `header=None` at all and use `names` instead?

Answer (score 562):

In order to read a csv in that doesn't have a header and for only certain columns you need to pass params `header=None` and `usecols=[3,6]` for the 4th and 7th columns:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, usecols=[3,6])
```

See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 17):

Make sure you specify pass `header=None` and add `usecols=[3,6]` for the 4th and 7th columns.

Answer (score 3):

As per documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html :
headerint, list of int, default ‘infer’
Row number(s) to use as the column names, and the start of the data. Default behavior is to infer the column names: if no names are passed the behavior is identical to header=0 and column names are inferred from the first line of the file, if column names are passed explicitly then the behavior is identical to header=None. Explicitly pass header=0 to be able to replace existing names. The header can be a list of integers that specify row locations for a multi-index on the columns e.g. [0,1,3]. Intervening rows that are not specified will be skipped (e.g. 2 in this example is skipped). Note that this parameter ignores commented lines and empty lines if skip_blank_lines=True, so header=0 denotes the first line of data rather than the first line of the file.

namesarray-like, optional
List of column names to use. If the file contains a header row, then you should explicitly pass header=0 to override the column names. Duplicates in this list are not allowed.

```
columts = ['Day', 'PLMN', 'RNCname']
tempo = pd.read_csv("info.csv", sep=';', header=0, names=columts, index_col=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also call `read_table()` with `header=None` (to read the first row of the file as the first row of the data):

```py
df = pd.read_table('test.tsv', sep=',', usecols=[3,6], header=None)
```

This function is more useful if the separator is `\t` (.tsv file etc.) because the default delimiter is `\t` (unlike `read_csv` whose default delimiter is `,`).