# pandas read in txt file without headers

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I am new to pandas and I thought it would be a good idea to give it a spin but as so often the first time appears to be not so easy.

I basically tried the following:
[Pandas read in table without headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287224/pandas-read-in-table-without-headers)

And I get the following error (unfortunately *Usecols do not match names* does not ring a bell since I set header to None):

> ValueError: Usecols do not match names.

here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

DATA_FOLDER = 'season_1/training_data/'

#data = np.loadtxt(DATA_FOLDER + 'order_data/order_data_sample', 
#                  dtype={'names': ('order_id', 'driver_id', 'passenger_id', 'start_district_hash',
#                                   'dest_distric_hash', 'price', 'time'),
#...                      'formats': ('S32', 'S32', 'S32', 'S32', 'S32', 'f6', 'f4')})

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(DATA_FOLDER + 'order_data/order_data_sample', parse_dates=[6], header=None, usecols=[3, 4, 6])
df
```

and my data:

```
97ebd0c6680f7c0535dbfdead6e51b4b  dd65fa250fca2833a3a8c16d2cf0457c  ed180d7daf639d936f1aeae4f7fb482f  4725c39a5e5f4c188d382da3910b3f3f  3e12208dd0be281c92a6ab57d9a6fb32  24  2016-01-01 13:37:23
92c3ac9251cc9b5aab90b114a1e363be  c077e0297639edcb1df6189e8cda2c3d  191a180f0a262aff3267775c4fac8972  82cc4851f9e4faa4e54309f8bb73fd7c  b05379ac3f9b7d99370d443cfd5dcc28  2 2016-01-01 09:47:54
abeefc3e2aec952468e2fd42a1649640  86dbc1b68de435957c61b5a523854b69  7029e813bb3de8cc73a8615e2785070c  fff4e8465d1e12621bc361276b6217cf  fff4e8465d1e12621bc361276b6217cf  9 2016-01-01 18:24:02
cb31d0be64cda3cc66b46617bf49a05c  4fadfa6eeaa694742de036dddf02b0c4  21dc133ac68e4c07803d1c2f48988a83  4b7f6f4e2bf237b6cc58f57142bea5c0  4b7f6f4e2bf237b6cc58f57142bea5c0  11  2016-01-01 22:13:27
139d492189ae5a933122c098f63252b3  NULL  26963cc76da2d8450d8f23fc357db987  fc34648599753c9e74ab238e9a4a07ad  87285a66236346350541b8815c5fae94  4 2016-01-01 17:00:06
```

I hope I have used the right tags for this...

Comment: Your seperator is not a comma (as assumed by read_csv), but whitespace. Use the sep keyword argument, or read the read_table documentation.

Comment: @mdurant thank you, this is helpful! I did not know about read_table before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and add parameter `names` for set new column names. Then you have to set `parse_dates=['c']`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""97ebd0c6680f7c0535dbfdead6e51b4b  dd65fa250fca2833a3a8c16d2cf0457c  ed180d7daf639d936f1aeae4f7fb482f  4725c39a5e5f4c188d382da3910b3f3f  3e12208dd0be281c92a6ab57d9a6fb32  24  2016-01-01 13:37:23
92c3ac9251cc9b5aab90b114a1e363be  c077e0297639edcb1df6189e8cda2c3d  191a180f0a262aff3267775c4fac8972  82cc4851f9e4faa4e54309f8bb73fd7c  b05379ac3f9b7d99370d443cfd5dcc28  2 2016-01-01 09:47:54
abeefc3e2aec952468e2fd42a1649640  86dbc1b68de435957c61b5a523854b69  7029e813bb3de8cc73a8615e2785070c  fff4e8465d1e12621bc361276b6217cf  fff4e8465d1e12621bc361276b6217cf  9 2016-01-01 18:24:02
cb31d0be64cda3cc66b46617bf49a05c  4fadfa6eeaa694742de036dddf02b0c4  21dc133ac68e4c07803d1c2f48988a83  4b7f6f4e2bf237b6cc58f57142bea5c0  4b7f6f4e2bf237b6cc58f57142bea5c0  11  2016-01-01 22:13:27
139d492189ae5a933122c098f63252b3  NULL  26963cc76da2d8450d8f23fc357db987  fc34648599753c9e74ab238e9a4a07ad  87285a66236346350541b8815c5fae94  4 2016-01-01 17:00:06"""
```

```
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),
                 sep="\s+", #or delim_whitespace=True, #separator is whitespace
                 header=None, #no header
                 usecols=[3, 4, 6], #parse only 3,4,6 columns
                 names=['a','b','c'], #set columns names
                 parse_dates=['c']) #parse datetime


print (df)
                                  a                                 b  \
0  4725c39a5e5f4c188d382da3910b3f3f  3e12208dd0be281c92a6ab57d9a6fb32   
1  82cc4851f9e4faa4e54309f8bb73fd7c  b05379ac3f9b7d99370d443cfd5dcc28   
2  fff4e8465d1e12621bc361276b6217cf  fff4e8465d1e12621bc361276b6217cf   
3  4b7f6f4e2bf237b6cc58f57142bea5c0  4b7f6f4e2bf237b6cc58f57142bea5c0   
4  fc34648599753c9e74ab238e9a4a07ad  87285a66236346350541b8815c5fae94   

           c  
0 2016-01-01  
1 2016-01-01  
2 2016-01-01  
3 2016-01-01  
4 2016-01-01 

print (df.dtypes)
a            object
b            object
c    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

If you need `time` too, add column `d` with `parse_dates=[['c', 'd']]`:

```
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),
                 delim_whitespace=True, 
                 usecols=[3, 4, 6, 7],
                 names=['a','b','c','d'],
                 parse_dates=[['c', 'd']])


print (df)
                  c_d                                 a  \
0 2016-01-01 13:37:23  4725c39a5e5f4c188d382da3910b3f3f   
1 2016-01-01 09:47:54  82cc4851f9e4faa4e54309f8bb73fd7c   
2 2016-01-01 18:24:02  fff4e8465d1e12621bc361276b6217cf   
3 2016-01-01 22:13:27  4b7f6f4e2bf237b6cc58f57142bea5c0   
4 2016-01-01 17:00:06  fc34648599753c9e74ab238e9a4a07ad   

                                  b  
0  3e12208dd0be281c92a6ab57d9a6fb32  
1  b05379ac3f9b7d99370d443cfd5dcc28  
2  fff4e8465d1e12621bc361276b6217cf  
3  4b7f6f4e2bf237b6cc58f57142bea5c0  
4  87285a66236346350541b8815c5fae94 

print (df.dtypes)
c_d    datetime64[ns]
a              object
b              object
dtype: object
```

Comment: thank you for helping me out! Pandas really works well since it is fast, too. I basically go with your solution. I only changed sep='\t'.

Comment: Super, if separator is `tab`, use `\t`. Glad can help you! Good luck!