# How to avoid NaN index values when Importing from .csv w/o headers to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, indexing

I have a `.csv` file without headers. I want to import it to create a pandas dataframe object.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(infile, global_sep, header = 0)
```

When doing `print df1.head()`, I yield the following output:

```
    1491895800000   -64  640  15424
0   1491895799995   -64  640  15424
1   1491895799990   -64  640  15424
2   1491895799985   -64  640  15424
3   1491895799980   -64  640  15424
4   1491895799975   -64  640  15424
```

Doing `df1.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True),` doesn't change the output.

**How to avoid NaN index values when Importing from .csv w/o headers to a pandas dataframe?**

When doing

```
print df1.iloc[0]
```

The output should be

```
0 1491895800000   -64  640  15424
```

Comment: related and probable dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287224/pandas-read-in-table-without-headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(infile, global_sep, header=None)
```

It will work.