# How to convert the header row to a normal row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a excel sheet where I skipped multiple rows and finally arrived at a dataframe with some little structure. But I have a dataframe which looks like this. Bold are headers.

[image]

There are some columns on top which I hid in this screenshot as well. While reading a dataframe by skipping rows from excel, there is a multi level indexing.
I wanted to have the numbers in header to come as a row. Please advice how to achieve this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas read in table without headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287224/pandas-read-in-table-without-headers)

Comment: could you add a snipshot from your excel file?

Comment: Sorry @PV8 cannot add it.  its not a duplicate one... because the one in the  forum you pointed out, just reads the excel directly by excluding rows. Whereas this is little different. From the dataframe, I need to make the header to row

Answer (score 2):

You can skip header with header = None if you use `.read_csv`

`df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, usecols=[3,6])`

Comment: not while reading a csv file. Because I also need the headers on top of it which forms multi level indexing.

Comment: Can you add a little more insight to your question, please.

Answer (score 1):

The following will add your current columns as the last row in the dataframe. You could then put this row into position `0`, or rename the columns, if necessary.

```
row = pd.Series(df.columns, index=df.columns)
df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```