# Problem in reading Data From Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a problem that drive me crazy:
Assume that we have a Dataframe like this

```
flowdemands = pd.read_excel('allinputs.xlsx', sheet_name='flowdemands')

Flow  Vnf   Demand
3      1         5
4      2        10
```

I wanna use read this DataFrame in this way..

```
for f in FlowSet
  for v in VnfSet 
    print('Flow Demand[{},{}]={}'.Format(f,v,FlowDemand(f,v))
```

I need somtinge Like 2 Dimension Array FlowDemad:

```
FlowDemand[3,1]=5
FlowDemand[4,2]=10
```

output should be like this

```
 FlowDemand[3,1]=5
 FlowDemand[4,2]=10
```

First dimension should be Flow and second dimension  should be Vnf
and Value of Array will be Demand(see above table)
Assume that we  have

```
FlowSet=[3,4] and VnfSet=[1,2]
```

Please help me to find appropriate data structure for solving this...
Note:
These are not my answer:
[Pandas read in table without headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287224/pandas-read-in-table-without-headers)
and this
[How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)
because I need to convert or store this dataframe to 2 dimension Array

---

By using Matrix this problem is solved:
FlowDemand=numpy.zeros((n_flowdemands+1,n_flowdemands+1),dtype=int)
FlowDemand[flowdemands.Flow,flowdemands.Vnf]=flowdemands.Demand

Comment: You can use `iterrows`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: I read that topic before, but I need something like matrix: FlowDemad[3,1]=5 FlowDemad[4,2]=10

Answer (score 1):

As [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway) said, you can use `iterrows` or `itertuples` to iterate over a pandas DataFrame

```
flowdemands = pd.read_excel('allinputs.xlsx', sheet_name='flowdemands')

for flow, vnf, demand in flowdemands.itertuples(index=False):
    print('Flow Demand[{},{}]={}'.format(flow, vnf, demand))
```

Though there are very few cases when you can rely on iterating a DataFrame. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/3440010) for more details.