# Adding missing label line

Tags: python, pandas

I csv have a file with data lines, but it misses the label line.
This label line is a string, coma separated, ready to be appended on top.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Trades-List.txt", sep=',')
labelLine = "label1,label2,label3"
```

How to add the 'labelLine' on top of data and make sure it is properly considered as the label line of the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas read in table without headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287224/pandas-read-in-table-without-headers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter `sep=','` is default, so should be removed, add `names` with splitted values for columns names:

```
labelLine = "label1,label2,label3"
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Trades-List.txt", names=labelLine.split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `names` parameter of [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) after splitting to list with [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split):

```
import pandas as pd

labelLine = "label1,label2,label3"

data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Trades-List.txt", sep=',',
                   names=labelLine.split(','))
```